# Installing Magento 1.9 on PHP 7

Tags: magento-1.9, php-7

I'm working on a localhost dev environment. For *some* reason, I decided to install PHP7 on the VM :-P. I also have WordPress and Magento 2 on the same VM, both of which have no issues with PHP7.

I've installed Magento 1.9 several times with no issues on other VMs (and ~PHP5.6), but this time the endpoint directs to "/magento1/index.php/install/" and returns a server 500 error. I see there is an extension that helps with PHP7 compatibility, but I assume that isn't helpful at the install phase. Is there a command-line install method for 1.9? I ended up going that route for Magento 2 and it was tops.

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first add extension from github in your magento 1 `app/code/local` folder from here,

[Magento 1 with PHP 7 Compatibility extension download from here](https://github.com/Inchoo/Inchoo_PHP7)

After that you can try to install magento 1 in your system. Now your installation should work fine.

Thanks.

Comment: Perfect! That did it. Whodathought that extensions could be installed/functional pre-installation. Thanks